# Retrive all districts based on city name from REST query

Tags: rest, here-api

I've searched for solution for that problem on [here-api](https://developer.here.com/documentation)  documentation but I can't really find it out ! I'm starting doubt if this even possible.

Ok so basicly what i need to know for now:
1. Is this even possible on this platform ?
2. Using exactly which 'module' (eg. PLATFORM DATA EXTENSION,BATCH GEOCODER)

Comment: Hello and welcome on StackOverflow!!! In order to get your a better answer, and your answer don't get deleted later on, you would have to read and follow some basic rules and conventions that will help everyone to communicate and help better. Please go to https://stackoverflow.com/help and read about the topic "What topics can I ask about here?", and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight solution to get all districts in a city since district concept varies from one place to another(country-specific). Still you can try one of the below options:

1. administrative-areas-buildings category in places api
2. city-town-village category in places api
3. retrieveAreas mode in geocoder api (apply bbox or increase the radius of prox parameter and see if it works for your location)
4. Search Text in geocoder can also be used if you are search for districts which match a regex

You can check if the above 1) and 2) are applicable to your location using https://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/categories/places?at=41.8369%2C-87.684&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg